# Wanting to move to USA and stay

Tags: usa, international-travel

I recently travelled to Florida on your typical theme parks holiday and I have fallen for the USA and have been wondering if it's possible for someone like me to be able to make the move!

I don't have a degree and I don't have sponsorship from a family member that lives there either. I am from the UK and currently live in the UK I can obviously get an ESTA but I have nothing that can get me a green card.

Is it possible to go over on the 90 day waiver and gain work and stay there and get a green card?

Comment: Hi James. This question might be more suited to the expatriates SE. This site is mainly for tourism travel and not longer term immigration. But to help you answer your question. No you cannot seek or partake in employment whilst on an ESTA visa waiver.

Comment: You can probably start by registering for the green card lottery next year :-)

Comment: @jcaron UK citizens [aren't eligible for green card lottery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_Immigrant_Visa#Ineligible_countries), there are too many 'normal' such migrants.

Comment: @AakashM Ah, I didn't know. Over 10K people from the UK immigrate to the US every year? Interesting to know.

Comment: T@AakashM UK *natives*.aren't eligible unless born in Northern Ireland.  Citizenship isn't relevant.

Comment: The USA isn't all sun, palm trees, alligators, and theme parks. Check out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrow,_Alaska) town.

Answer (score 5):

> I don't have a degree and I don't have sponsorship from a family
>   member that lives there either.

That makes meeting the requirements for a residence permit a lot harder, but it might still be possible.

> I am from the UK and currently live in the UK I can obviously get an ESTA but I have nothing that can get me a green card.

Nothing gained, nothing won. Contact your nearest consulate or embassy and ask for assistance, nothing to lose.

> Is it possible to go over on the 90 day waiver and gain work and stay there and get a green card?

Do NOT go that way. You'd be an illegal immigrant subject to removal from the country which would also earn you a ban on visiting the US for several years AND make getting a residence permit a lot harder if not impossible.

So contact the US consulate or embassy, and ask for assistance. They no doubt have experience with that question and will be able to point you in the right direction to get the paperwork and other requirements going.

Do keep in mind that this process can take several years to complete, so don't put up your house for sale just yet.